# Why doesn't tinder.com redirect to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts?

Tags: hosts-file

In my /etc/hosts file in macOS Mojave 10.14.6 I have

```
127.0.0.1 someotherdistraction.com
127.0.0.1 https://www.tinder.com
127.0.0.1 https://tinder.com
127.0.0.1 www.tinder.com
```

someotherdistraction.com's redirect works just fine - why doesn't tinders?
I have also tried hard refresh/clear caches to no avail.

Comment: I don't know the full ruleset of etc/hosts so I can't provide a full answer, but you don't need the protocol `http://` etc. You do need to cover all eventualities on domains that have CDN or other outlying structures, so you might need such as `www.tinder.com` `tinder.com` `cdn.tinder.com` or a slew of other related domains.

Comment: Entries containing the protocol are invalid and will be ignored. The hosts file is only for DNS entries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Tetsujin and @Robert I removed protocols from the file and added `cdn.tinder.com` to the list which seemed to do the trick in multiple browsers (safari and chromium). /etc/hosts now reads

```
...
127.0.0.1 tinder.com
127.0.0.1 www.tinder.com
127.0.0.1 cdn.tinder.com
```

and displays an error page 'This site can’t be reached'

Comment: "and redirects to" is incomplete. There is something missing from your answer.